# Codeigniter - Moving complicated IF statements out of the View

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a project thats means I'm dealing with lots of dates and I have one view where a user can see an overview of various events, for the coming week.

The view shows multiple events for multiple accounts.

The problem I am facing is that my view has some pretty complex IF statements (checking the current date, checking the event date, checking the account id against the event etc) and its starting to look messy and I'm sure it could be done easier/more streamlined!

How would I go about moving an IF statement to the controller?

I tried looking up best practices for CI but nothing useful comes up.

Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need some [presenter classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) on top of your models where you can shove all these conditionals and gave them some descriptive names.

Comment: Would it help to split your view in several pieces, do your if (either in controller or in the "master" view), and depending on the result load a certain piece?

Answer (score 1):

i would have a seperate function (within the controller or a library) that is used to prepare the data. this function only needs to return an array so that the data can be constructed in the HTML without the need for all the conditional checks.

This is an example of a data prepration library, it won't just work so you will need to create a full library, it is just to give you a general idea.

```
<?php
class prepare {
    function prep_page_data($page_id) {

        $output = array();

        $query = $this->ci->db->get_where("page_data", array("page_id" => $page_id));

        foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $output = $row;
            //complete all addtional checks below
            if($row['datetime'] < date("Y-m-d 00:00:00")) {
                $output['archive'] = "old"
            }
            else {
                $output['archive'] = "new";
            }
            //you can add as many conditions as you like to complete the data collection.
        }

        return $output;

    }
}

?>
```